# Trying to cut and paste an image from excel to my email, it is working, just not right

Tags: excel, vba

Well, this one is interesting. So I have this template that loads up items from a sharepoint list, and then I do things with the items.

One of the things that I need to do is to be able to take a screen shot of the excel doc, attach it to an email, and send it out. The thing is that I am using a template excel doc that sits in a folder on a shared drive. From this template I create reports everyday. This part works fine, it is just the cut and paste issue, it seems that the way this is working is that it will only take the screen shot from the template document and add it to the template document, not the one that I just created, which is what need.

Anyway, my code:

```
    run_date = Date
    Dim s2 As String
    s2 = Format(run_date, "MM-dd-yyyy")
    Dim FS As Object

Dim FullPath As String
FullPath = "\\path\Report\Reports\Status Reports\Daily\DailyReportStatusFor" + s2 + ".xlsm"

        Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        objXL.DisplayAlerts = False
        objXL.Application.Workbooks.Open FullPath
        Set objActiveWkbk = objXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook

' Where you will enter Sharepoint location path
    objXL.Application.Workbooks.Open FullPath



            objXL.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
                "https://Sharepoint/lists/shared documents/DailyReportStatusFor" + s2 + ".xlsm", FileFormat:=1, CreateBackup:=False


   Range("'owssvr'!A1:O18").CopyPicture
   Sheets("Image").Select
   Range("A1").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste

Dim objOLApp As Object    'Outlook.Application
Dim outItem As Object    'Outlook.MailItem
Dim outFolder As Object    'MAPIFolder
Dim DestFolder As Object    'MAPIFolder
Dim outNameSpace As Object    'NameSpace
Dim lngAttachment As Long
SendFrom = "me@me.com"
SendTo = "me@me.com" 
ccTo = "me@me.com"
EmailSubject = "Dashboard - Daily Review Status for " + s2
EmailBody = "Attached is the  Dashboard - Daily Review Status for " + s2
'Set application settings
With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
End With

Sheets("Image").Select
Range("A1").Select
Set Sendrng = Selection
With Sendrng

ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False
With .Parent.MailEnvelope
With .Item

.Subject = EmailSubject 
.To = SendTo 
.CC = ccTo 
.SentOnBehalfOfName = SendFrom     
.Attachments.Add ("\\Path to report\Report\Reports\Status Reports\Daily\DailyReportStatusFor" + s2 + ".xlsm")
.Body = "Attached is the Dashboard - Daily Review Status for " + s2
.Send
End With
End With
'Outlook_SendEmail = True
End With
     objXL.ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False


   ' objXL.Application.COMAddIns("AmericanExpress.ExcelMetadataAddin").Connect = True
    objXL.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set objActiveWkbk = Nothing
    objXL.Application.Quit
    Set objXL = Nothing
    Set objNet = Nothing
    Set FS = Nothing
    Set App = Nothing
    Set Itm = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: It's not clear what workbook/sheet you're trying to copy from - I assume that code is working okay? And what workbook/sheet are you trying to paste it into - FullPath or SaveAs file?

Comment: So I am trying to copy from the workbook that I am in using this code here:           
                    Range("'owssvr'!A1:O18").CopyPicture
                    Sheets("Image").Select
                    Range("A1").Select
                    ActiveSheet.Paste

Comment: I'm asking what workbooks is sheet "owssvr" located

Comment: It's in the template that I use and it is in the excel documents that are created using the template.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming CopyPicture is working as designed, you probably need to reopen the path

After

```
Range("'owssvr'!A1:O18").CopyPicture
```

and Before this line

```
Sheets("Image").Select
```

Insert line between the two lines:

```
 Set objActiveWkbk = objXL.Application.Workbooks.Open FullPath
```

Comment: Sadly doesn't help - what gives you the error - I'm just using the same lines you use in your own code. What's your new code - and what line gives you the error and what is the error message. You can help us help you

Comment: the error was coming from this line that you had me add:Set objActiveWkbk = objXL.Application.Workbooks.Open FullPath which I changed to say this: objXL.Application.Workbooks.Open FullPath after it threw a syntax error on that line. After I changed it, it still didn't work, saying that something was wrong with this line: Range("'owssvr'!A1:O18").CopyPicture.

Comment: I can see you're having issues reading my siggestions. If you're getting an error on the CopyPicture line it must mean yiu didn't follow instructions to put the OpenPath statement AFTER that line - not BEFORE it. If you're going to change things or not copy/paste suggestions - then edit your original post and insert your amended code at the bottom with an EDIT statement.

Comment: Ok, so this is going to suck a little for me, but I am afraid that I have figured it out, It was in my console application, I was calling the path to the template instead of the document it created. Sorry for wasting all your time, but I do really appreciate all your time helping me out.

Comment: Being new to the site, it's probably worth mentioning that people appreciate any little acknowledgement - and upvoting helpful replies is one way to show it. Enjoy your time on SO